# Production Environment in Symfony does not work

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, production, symfony-3.3

[image]
This appears, when I switch from `app_dev.php` to `app.php`.

---

Apache log:

```
[:error] [pid 2729] [client 192.168.77.11:50643] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of ProxyManager\\Configuration::setGeneratorStrategy() must be an instance of ProxyManager\\void, none returned in /var/www/dvm/vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php:124\nStack trace:\n
#0 /var/www/dvm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/ProxyManager/LazyProxy/Instantiator/RuntimeInstantiator.php(37): ProxyManager\\Configuration->setGeneratorStrategy(Object(ProxyManager\\GeneratorStrategy\\EvaluatingGeneratorStrategy))\n
#1 /var/www/dvm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(628): Symfony\\Bridge\\ProxyManager\\LazyProxy\\Instantiator\\RuntimeInstantiator->__construct()\n
#2 /var/www/dvm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(577): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->getContainerBuilder()\n
#3 /var/www/dvm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(486): Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->buildContainer()\n
#4 /var/www/dvm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kerne in /var/www/dvm/vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php on line 124
```

I did everything like in http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html
**What's I doing wrong?**

---

**EDIT:**
I have 7.1 php [image][image]

Comment: Hey, why minuses?! What's wrong with the question? If you need additional info, ask me. I'll send all you ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOS/user-bundle ProxyManager\Configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304889/fos-user-bundle-proxymanager-configuration-error)

Comment: @jkucharovic this is not my case at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the same problem setting up php version on composer.json with this:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0.18"
    },
}
```

Then composer update the packages according to that php version.

Comment: I have `"require": {"php": ">=7.1", ...}` in `composer.json`.

Answer (score -1):

You use PHP 7.0, but have installed [`ocramius/proxy-manager`](https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager) version 2.1.x which require PHP 7.1.

Look at difference at these two versions: [`v2.0.x`](https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager/blob/2.0.4/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php#L136-L144) vs [`v2.1.x`](https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager/blob/2.1.0/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php#L121-L124).

There are two solutions:

- upgrade PHP to version 7.1
- downgrade ocramius/proxy-manager to version 2.0.x.

Comment: I have PHP 7.1 version

Comment: @DmitriyKorobkov It's CLI version of PHP. Check your `mod_php` by `phpinfo();`

Comment: Also php7.1 in phpinfo(). Screenshot added.